# MVC alternatives: examples of MVA & AVC?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-adapter

I'm interested in learning about the alternative patterns to Model-View-Controller, specifically the **Model-View-Adapter** and **Application-View-Controller** patterns.

Google results tend to be either a high-level overview or Java-based.

Can anyone either provide, or point me to, an example of these patterns in either PHP, Python or JavaScript?

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with MVC, but sometimes the problem doesn't fit exactly with that pattern. MVA seems as though it could help with my particular task, but I could do with an example to be sure.

Comment: look also at the DCI (data, contexts and interactions) architecture

Comment: there is also PAC (Presentation Abstraction Controller) described in POSA1 and MVVM (Model View ViewModel) and MVP (Model View Presenter) by Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 1):

These are some alternatives lurking about my bookmarks. They're mostly Java based but you shouldn't have any problems in understanding the underlying patterns.

- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2000/jw-0721-hmvc.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx
- http://www.mindsilver.com/guide/docs/articles/mvc/index.php

Answer (score 0):

This could be "python" enough:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_View_Controller
You should look at that framework, although patterns aren't frameworks and understanding frameworks won't necessary make you understand the pattern.

Comment: The GoF authors suggest we understand patterns in the perspective we implement them, including languages, including frameworks.

Comment: @Radek Patterns can be described as solutions for problems in a certain context. What I say is that you get different solutions for the same problem in different contexts, what you say is that you need to know the context to apply the solution I guess.
I saw people many times think the solutions only are the patterns and therefore I want to stress their wider scope.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from AVC description on its site, AVC is not a design pattern, it's a framework for python (and for jython as well).

That's why I think that your question is incorrect.